# Is there a boost::timer-like class in Qt?

Tags: qt, boost, timer

Yes we can get a copy of timer.hpp from boost and modify it to use in a Qt project. But for consistency I wonder if Qt has such a Class I never know.

Comment: What did you find when you Googled it, and how does that not solve your problem?

Comment: to John Zwinck: I'm glad to do so if google is available all the time in my country. I'm regret that you didn't help me.

Comment: Well I hope some worthwhile search engine is available in your country.  If not, consider using a proxy to bypass your oppressive regime.

Comment: @HaiyuanLi - It would be really helpful if you would explain a little more about what functionality you are trying to achieve for the people that don't know what boost::timer actually does differently from the QTimer that comes with Qt. Spent at least 10 more seconds typing out some more description and people will help you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

there is QTimer in Qt, but not sure how it differ from boost::timer

Comment: -1 This is a poor answer, the two APIs are very different because they're aimed different things. QTimer is essentially a countdown mechanism that fires a signal when finished.  Whilst Boost.Timer is designed for accurate timing of code blocks e.g. `QTime` and `QTimer` only operate to millisecond accuracy but Boost.Timer aims at nanosecond (but is constrained but the platform to usually around microsecond levels).

Comment: thanks for clarification, but as it seems, answer helped Haiyuan Li anyway